# How to customize bcrypt?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bcrypt

I have built a working API using rails using [this](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/token-based-authentication-with-ruby-on-rails-5-api) PluralSight blog. In my app for user verification I've used gems like `bcrypt` and `jwt`. I am using MySQL as my database and have a User table named `users`.

Which looks like this:

[image: Current User Table]
But then I saw my production Database which looks like this: [image: Desired User Table]

Since then I have done quite a research and found out that while using latest version of `bcrypt` it is must to have `password_digest` as a column, I cant store *Encrypted Password* and *Password Salt* separately.
But the problem is I can't change the schema of existing table. Kindly let me know if there's any work around? Or there exists any better approach to tackle this issue.

Answer (score 2):

It *is* possible and isn't actually difficult. I'll show you a step-by-step procedure that helps understand how to do that.

## How passwords work under the hood

We start by locating [`has_secure_password`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/SecurePassword/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_secure_password). It's defined in `ActiveModel::SecurePassword::ClassMethods`. `ActiveModel::SecurePassword` is an Active Model concern responsible for passwords. It's included into `ActiveRecord::Base`.

If we look [at the source code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/18a2513729ab90b04b1c86963e7d5b9213270c81/activemodel/lib/active_model/secure_password.rb#L53) we can see that it [includes `InstanceMethodsOnActivation`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/18a2513729ab90b04b1c86963e7d5b9213270c81/activemodel/lib/active_model/secure_password.rb#L83). It defines four instance methods:

1. [`authenticate`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/18a2513729ab90b04b1c86963e7d5b9213270c81/activemodel/lib/active_model/secure_password.rb#L94) - it build `BCrypt::Password` based on the value returned by `password_digest` (normally this is a column accessor) and tests whether it matches `unencrypted_password`.
2. [`password`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/18a2513729ab90b04b1c86963e7d5b9213270c81/activemodel/lib/active_model/secure_password.rb#L98) - an ordinary attribute reader.
3. [`password=`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/18a2513729ab90b04b1c86963e7d5b9213270c81/activemodel/lib/active_model/secure_password.rb#L112) - a custom attribute setter. It converts an assignment to `password` into an assignment to `password_digest`. Remember that in Ruby all these "assignments" are really method calls. In other words, this method translates a call to `#password=` into a call to `#password_digest=`.
4. [`password_confirmation=`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/18a2513729ab90b04b1c86963e7d5b9213270c81/activemodel/lib/active_model/secure_password.rb#L122) - an ordinary attribute writer.

Based on the above code, you can see that you the model needs to implement two methods to be compatible with Rails secure passwords. These methods are `#password_digest` and `#password_digest=`. `ActiveModel::SecurePassword` doesn't care whether they are backed by database columns! From its perspective, they are perfectly ordinary Ruby methods.

## Implementation

We know that `#password_digest` needs to assemble a BCrypt digest based on the two columns in our database. Conversely, `#password_digest=` needs to disassemble a BCrypt digest into salt and checksum.

Let's write a simple test case help us ensure the code works. Our goal is to make this test pass.

```
require 'test_helper'

class UserTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  NAME = 'gregnavis'.freeze
  PASSWORD = '1234abcd'.freeze

  test 'passwords work' do
    # First, we store the user in the database to check that the fields are
    # serialized correctly.
    User.create!(name: NAME,
                 password: PASSWORD,
                 password_confirmation: PASSWORD)

    # Second, we reload the model to ensure that it works even if we reset
    # state that isn't serialized to the database.
    user = User.find_by_name!(NAME)

    # Third, let's see whether authentication works.
    assert(user.authenticate(PASSWORD))
    assert_not(user.authenticate("#{PASSWORD}1"))
  end
end
```

Looking at the source code of [`#password=`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/18a2513729ab90b04b1c86963e7d5b9213270c81/activemodel/lib/active_model/secure_password.rb#L118) we can see the method receives an instance of `BCrypt::Password` as an argument. [The docs for `BCrypt::Password`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/codahale/bcrypt-ruby/BCrypt/Password) list `salt` (which includes the salt, version, and cost) and `checksum` as attributes. This means the following implementation should pass the test:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_secure_password

  def password_digest
    # We need to glue the two parts.
    "#{password_salt}#{password_hash}"
  end

  def password_digest=(digest)
    # We need to split the BCrypt::Password into two parts.
    self.password_salt = digest.salt
    self.password_hash = digest.checksum
  end
end
```

That's it! The test is green. I also confirmed that joining `digest.salt` and `digest.checksum` gives the complete hash. I did that in the console.